# Laravel - Make global variable in Model to use only inside the Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have two variables in my Model that i use in a few functions

```
$firstDayThisYear = Carbon::create(date('Y'), 1, 1, 0);
$lastDayThisYear = Carbon::create(date('Y'), 12, 31, 0);
```

how can i extract them and make them global to use them only inside of my Model?

i know it must be protected...but I am not sure if i need to put it like this:

```
protected static $firstDayThisYear = Carbon::create(date('Y'), 1, 1, 0);
protected static $lastDayThisYear = Carbon::create(date('Y'), 12, 31, 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use these variables in one model, just do this:

```
protected $firstDayThisYear;

public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->firstDayThisYear = Carbon::create(date('Y'), 1, 1, 0);
}
```

Then use it with `$this->firstDayThisYear`.

Also, you could get start of the year and start of the last day of the year with:

```
Carbon::now()->startOfYear();
Carbon::now()->endOfYear()->startOfDay();
```

I guess it's more readable.

Comment: OK, actually i just want to use it inside the model for a few functions....i'm not going to use it outside of the model...

Comment: do you know maybe how to write this more readable `$firstDayNextYear = Carbon::create(date('Y')+1, 1, 1, 0);`

Comment: Yes, I was gonna to write `Carbon::now()->addYear()->startOfYear();` but it does the same. )

Comment: Hmm this is not working good because my variable is visible outside the model

Comment: Can you tell me how do you check this.

Comment: with die and dump dd(Model)

Comment: @lewis4u but you can't access `protected`, change it etc. You've unchecked my answer and checked another answer which says about `private`. But there is no any difference between `private` and `protected` properties if only you do not inherit the model. You still will see `private` variable if you'll run `dd(Model)`

Comment: You are right.....but nothing works....i can't declare a carbon variable..i get this error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' for this `protected $now = Carbon::now();` and for this also `protected $now = Carbon::now();` can you please try?

Comment: Oh yes, you should use constructor here. I've updated the code.

Comment: Can this public constructor be protected constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128456/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-alexey-mezenin).

Comment: @lewis4u do you get any error? I've just checked and it works just fine.

Comment: i solved it now.....i called the variable like this `$firstDayThisYear` instead of `$this->$firstDayThisYear` thanks to Ricardo i solved it!!! But he is right about private variable....it must be private! there is a difference between private and protected! http://jordizle.com/lab/98/public-private-protected-in-php-5

Comment: If you'll call variable with `$var` instead of `$this->var` in one of methods inside the model, you'll get `Undefined variable` exception. You're doing something wrong. And I know the difference between private and protected. You usually want to use protected since in future you may want to use inheritance.

Comment: Can you believe this: Now when i make all these variables in a constructor my soft deleted users are visible in a view....why is that? because i'm overriding the base Model class constructor or what?

Comment: @lewis4u yes, you need to call parent constructor. Thanks for mentioning that, I've updated the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've attempted to do it won't work because PHP doesn't let you use an "expression" as a default value for a property like that.

If you insist on having them `static` then you should create a static method to achieve this. You could do something like:

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected static $firstDayOfThisYear;

    protected static function firstDayOfThisYear()
    {
        if (!static::$firstDayOfThisYear) {
            static::$firstDayOfThisYear = Carbon::create(date('Y'), 1, 1, 0);
        }

        return static::$firstDayOfThisYear;
    }

    public function useIt()
    {
        $firstDay = static::firstDayOfThisYear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i don't need a static at all...i just want to have this variable available inside the model an not out....

Comment: In which case, you can just declare a private or protected property and initialise it in your constructor. Private makes the object only accessible to the class you're in, but protected is available to subclasses.

Comment: yes, thanks...i solved it finally with some help of Alexey and Ricardo

Answer (score 1):

If you just want this fields to be available just inside the Model, so declare it as private instead.

Comment: Yesss...this is what i was looking for! `private $firstDayThisYear = Carbon::now()->startOfYear();`